# Alienware 14 won't reboot with lid closed - Window 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

System is only two week old.  My PC is connected to a Samsung HD monitor via HDMI.  The lid of the PC is closed when connected to the external monitor.  When I reboot the system with the lid closed, the system in non-responsive and wont' reboot. The only key that woks is the Caps Lock.  I need to power-off the PC and restart using the power button with the lid open.  The system boots up with the lid open and then transfer the video to the external monitor.  I have tried everything, including updating all drivers, Windows updates, reading plenty of forum advises and speaking with Dell, who provided little to no support.  I have updated the driver in the "ACPI lid" properties via device manager and edited the regedit.exe command to create a Lid always open "DWord" with a value of 1, but nothing worked.  Other than having the PC lid open at all times in order to reboot without shuting-down, any other suggestions?

Mainboard : Alienware 07MJ2Y

> Chipset : Intel Haswell
>
> Processor : Intel P6 @ 2500   MHz  (max : 3100)
>
> Physical Memory : 4096  MB  (1 x 4096 DDR3-SDRAM )
>
> Video Card : Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 & Nvidia GT 750M
>
> Hard Disk : ATA WDC WD7500BPKT-7 SCSI Disk Device (750GB)
>
> DVD-Rom Drive : HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GS40N
>
> Monitor Type : Samsung T24C550 - 23 inches
>
> Network Card : Attansic (Now owned by Atheros)
>
> Network Card : Atheros Communications AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
>
> Operating System : Windows 7 Home Premium Home Edition Media Center 6.01.7601 Service Pack 1 (64-bit)
>
> DirectX : Version 11.00

Comment: What's the BIOS version? Do you get the same issue after [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: Yes, I did update the Bios version to the latest from the Dell site, V8.

Comment: Unplug everything from the computer. Press Win+R, type `shutdown /r /t 60` in the text box, and press Enter. Then Close the lid, and wait for the system to restart. See whether you get the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Windows gave me a message that it would shut down in 1 minute and I closed the lid as instructed, and nothing.  The background lights of the PC were on, but the screen was off and the system did not reboot.  I attempted it a couple of times, with everything disconnected and same results.  Other suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to shutdown, put into sleep mode, and hibernate Windows properly? Does the computer hang only when it's supposed to restart?

Comment: The PC will sleep and hibernate with no problem, however, it will not wake with the lid closed.  The system will only wake-up with the lid in an open position.  I have a wireless mouse attached to the system and the PC will not respond to the mouse movement (in order to wake up) until the lid, as previously said, is open.

Answer (score 0):

Try and change the Power Option settings for the "When I close the Lid:" to Do Nothing under the Plugged in Category.

Comment: I did change the power options under Windows and Alienware Command Control Panel.  Nothing worked.